# Aggregate function Count() using dynamic linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I am trying to use `Aggregate function` **Count()** on some column using dynamic linq query but I am not able to achieve, what I am exactly looking  is

```
Select Count(Id),Id 
from Table1 
Group By Id 
Having Count(Id) > 1
```

I want to convert the same query to dynamic linq query, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: use let keyword with having value Count(ID) and then construct linq query

Comment: stackoverflow partially becoming sql to linq translater

Comment: Finally I was able to solve. got solution from the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531679/how-to-write-this-linq-sql-as-a-dynamic-query-using-strings

Comment: You might want to post what your solution was here and mark it as the selected answer for anyone else searching to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127406/get-non-distinct-elements-from-an-ienumerable):

```
var distinctItems = 
    from list in itemsList
    group list by list.ItemCode into grouped
    where grouped.Count() > 1
    select grouped;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following two queries will give you the exact same result:
first with lambda second result without.

```
        var Table1 = new List<Row>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < i + m; x++)
                {
                    Table1.Add(new Row() { Id = m });
                }
            }
        }

        var result = Table1.GroupBy(row => row.Id)
                    .Where(p => p.Count() > 1);

        var resultB = from row in Table1
                      group row by row.Id into rowGrouped
                      where rowGrouped.Count() > 1
                      select rowGrouped;

        foreach (var r in resultB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID {0} count: {1}", r.Key, r.Count());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

May be something like this

```
list.GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => new {
                         Id = group.Key, 
                         Count = group.Count() });
```

Comment: I want solution using DynamicLinq query.. what ever you suggested was using regular Linq query.